# Capture Postgresql Trafic to replay it on another database

Tags: postgresql, packet-capture, mirroring

In order to check if a new version of the database (in staging) react the same way (or better) than the production database,   I would like to capture all requests execute on production server, .. to replay them on the staging database.

Is there a tool that does this job ?
what would be interesting is the abality to compare execution time, when replay, and highlight queries executed slower.

Else, I thought I would catpure queries by configuring '0' to log_min_statement_duration (so that queries can be logged in postgresql logfile), and then parse the file to grab and re play request on other server.... is there a better way to do it ?

(current database version postgresql9.6, but I'm interesting even if it's for higher version.. for next time)

Comment: Your could try [Streaming replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION)

Comment: There is pgreplay, although it has not impressed me with its robustness or easy of use.

Comment: thanks @jjanes ! on the description, it does exactly what I need.. hope that robustness and ease of use will be ok for me ! :)

Comment: @Steeeve - I don't think so - I have to reproduce the workload, with 'select' activity. I think 'streaming replication' wouldn't help me on this.   So far, pgreplay is the only tool I found to do it.   Though, as jjanes said, .. it lacks some options / features to be an impressive tool :)   well, .. it helped me quite a lot ,  so I'm rather grateful that it exists ! :)